# Linq to SQL "not like" operator

Tags: sql, linq

I have a simple SQL statement.

Select distinct value from tablename where value not like '%TEST%'

How do I write this in Linq to SQL syntax.

I tried the below statement but it doesnt seem to work.

```
var p = (from c in tablename where !(c.value.ToUpper().Contains("%TEST%")) 
        select c.Value).Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: You dont need to use %TEST% the percent in Contains.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is the "%" - you're looking for things which literally don't contain "%TEST%" which would probably be everything. I think you mean:

```
var p = (from c in tablename
         where !c.Value.ToUpper().Contains("TEST")
         select c.Value).Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: ninja'ed. -.- how can you be so fast.

Comment: He has an AI written in C# with Auto Reply.

Comment: Wow. That was quick. Thanks..Worked like a charm.

Comment: also this will not return `NULL` records, if you need `NULL` then add extra condition like `c.Value == null`

Answer (score 4):

If you were stuck with a pattern for sql to match, you could use [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx)

```
string pattern = "%TEST%";
  ...
from c in tablename
where !SqlMethods.Like(c.Value, pattern)
select c
```