# Linq not contains dynamic query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq to SQL “not like” operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513319/linq-to-sql-not-like-operator)

How can I write a dynamic linq query with using not contains?

I use `.Contains()` instead of like. But what should I use instead of `not like`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use `!` before the contains condition. Like

```
 var myProducts = from p in products
                  where !productList.Contains(p.ID)
                  select p;
```

Comment: I just put the mark to wrong place. thanks @habib

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this should help...

```
YourDataContext dc = new YourDataContext(); 
    var query =     
        from c in dc.Customers     
        where !(from o in dc.Orders     
                select o.CustomerID)     
               .Contains(c.CustomerID)     
        select c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `!` operator. Like this:

```
private List<int> iList = new List<int>
            {
                1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
            };

    if (!iList.Contains(888))
                {

                }
```