# Check if a String value contains any number by using Lambda Expression

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a `SQL` query that retrieves only the names not containing any number:

```
...
WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

On the other hand, when trying to use this query in `Lambda Expression` with different combinations as shown below, none of them is working does not work:

```
.Where(m => !m.EmployeeName.Contains("%[0-9]%")
```

or

```
 .Where(m => !m.EmployeeName.Contains(".*[0-9].*")
```

How can I use `NOT LIKE` method in `Lambda Expression`?

**Update:** My lambda expression is shown below:

```
return Json(db.TEmployees
    .Where(m => m.Status == Enums.Status.Active)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(m => !Regex.IsMatch(m.EmployeeName, ".*[0-9].*"))
    .Select(m => new { ID = m.EmployeeID, EmployeeName = m.EmployeeName }), 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513319/linq-to-sql-not-like-operator

Comment: @Venki I already know that, but I need a solution with [0-9]. Please read my question carefully!

Comment: need ToList() for json data please again my answer @binary

Comment: Please do not post answers inside the question itself, instead post a new answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far I know you can't apply regular expression in Linq to Entities. What I recommend to do is  if you have other conditions call `Where` method using them first, and then call `AsEnumerable` to work with Linq to Object which allows you use regular expressions, so you can apply the condition you need:

```
var query= context.YourDbSet.Where(...)
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(m => !Regex.IsMatch(m.EmployeeName, @"\d"));
```

Or you can also do the following:

```
var query= context.YourDbSet.Where(...)
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(e=>e.!EmployeeName.Any(char.IsDigit));
```

### Update:

A third solution could be using [DbSet.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) method to execute your raw SQL query:

```
var query= context.YourDbSet.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'");
```

Translating that to your scenario would be:

```
                     // This column names must match with 
                     //  the property names in your entity, otherwise use *
return Json(db.TEmployees.SqlQuery("SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeName 
                                    FROM Employees 
                                    WHERE Status=1 AND Name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'"), 
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);// Change the value in the first condition for the real int value that represents active employees
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of them not returns any records (even if the other ones). Anyway, do you know how can I use sql query in this situation that corresponding to my lambda expression above (I added update)? Any idea?

Comment: Hi @binary, check my Update

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I also post the final status of my method in my question above so that others can also use it. Regards...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex.IsMatch`.

```
yourEnumerable.Where(m => !Regex.IsMatch(m.EmployeeName, @"\d"));
```

Comment: Actually I had also tried to use !Regex but in that case no record is returning. Any idea?

Comment: Try this pattern instead ^[0-9]*$

Comment: Thanks but not retrieved any records. Any idea?

Comment: I simulated this, and this pattern worked @"\d". My test data was
`sss213, ggg, g1g, 1gg, xxx`. It returned only "ggg" and "xxx"

Comment: I tested again but not returning any data. Could you have  a look at my lambda expression shown above in the Update?

Answer (score 2):

EF is limited in its capability to generate the exact SQL you want.  I do not know of a specific expression that will generate the pattern `[0-9]` in your `LIKE` clause.

The list of [String Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738534(v=vs.100).aspx)
 that are supported by EF are documented on MSDN.  None of which can be used to determine if a string contains an arbitrary digit or not.

Some other options are:

- Use the *exact* SQL you want in C# and call [`ExecuteStoreCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Return more objects than you need from the DB and filter in memory using `AsEnumerable()`

The Equivalent SQL would be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM TEmployees
WHERE Status = {code for active status}
  AND Name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Comment: In that case I think the best idea to use SQL Query in EF. Could you please clarify me about how can I transform the lambda expression above (in update) to the SQL Query in EF?

Answer (score 1):

Try this more information [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540620/check-if-a-string-has-at-least-one-number-in-it-using-linq) :

```
return Json(db.TEmployees
.Where(m => m.Status == Enums.Status.Active && !m.EmployeeName.Any(char.IsDigit))
.Select(m => new { ID = m.EmployeeID, EmployeeName = m.EmployeeName }).ToList(), 
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**EDIT:** Add ToList() in return json

Comment: Thanks, I also look at that page but not worked. Any idea?

Comment: EF does not support the expression `char.IsDigit`

Comment: last one add AsEnumarable() and try again please check my edit @binary

Comment: Just to note, this will not execute the filter in the SQL. It will return all the rows from the database and then filter them.

Comment: I checked again but returns no data as well.

Comment: I found your fault you must add ToList() ins json return please check edit again i hope this helps to you @binary

Comment: Sorry, but in that case it throws error for the NULL values. I solved the problem by using pure sql query. Thanks, voted+

Answer (score 1):

The only solution using Linq-To-Entities I can think of is to define a string array and see if your string contains any of them:

```
string[] digits = new { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
...Where(m => !digits.Any(m.EmployeeName.Contains(d));
```

I can imagine this will be a slow query though for big datasets, so I would just execute the sql through EF.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. So, I think the best idea to use SQL Query in EF. Could you please clarify me about how can I transform the lambda expression above (in update) to the SQL Query in EF? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There is no general **LINQ to Entities** solution.

However, if you target **only** Sql Server database, you can use [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex(v=vs.110).aspx) canonical function like this:

```
db.TEmployees
    .Where(m => m.Status == Enums.Status.Active &&
        SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[0-9]%", m.EmployeeName) == 0)
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but without using lambda I can also use sql query and I solved the problem with it. Voted+